# Comma in a series of two series?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

I'm writing some documentation for code I'm writing and had a question regarding commas with a series of two series.

`You cannot add setting_A and setting_B, or setting_X and setting_Y in the same request.`

Do I include the comma after setting_b? I'm not sure since a series of two items doesn't use one (I saw **zebras and penguins** at the zoo.). I'm just confused since each of the 'items' is actually a series in and of itself (A and B; X and Y).

Comment: Since you're documenting code, I would put brackets around each pair, just to be ultra-clear.  Then the comma is an optional stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference :

[Commas with Lists](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/)

> Give correct comma usage as "I cleaned the house and garage, *raked the lawn* **and/or** *took out the garbage*".

The items "setting_A and setting_B" and "setting_X and setting_Y" are self contained list items and can be used in a list separated by a comma.  No comma is required within the list item, so a correct comment would be:

> You cannot add setting_A and setting_B, setting_C and setting_D or setting_X and setting_Y in the same request.

Note that a comma after "setting_D" is also correct in US english and called an Oxford or serial comma.

However, the commas with lists rule only applies to three or more items and your example only has two list items, the the correct comment is

> You cannot add setting_A and setting_B or setting_X and setting_Y in the same request.

Despite this being grammatically accurate, I agree with the comment above. Code comments often forgo grammatical accuracy for technical accuracy, therefore the most appropriate sentence formation in this case would be:

> /* You cannot add (setting_A and setting_B) or (setting_X and setting_Y) in the same request */

Comment: I’d agree with Isobella but what’s that ‘raked the lawn and/or took out the garbage’ please? How could ’raked the lawn or took out the garbage’ be correct or useful?
I’d think Sam’s question reasonable except what are these ‘You cannot…’ or ‘or’?
What happened to the the scientific method, which insists that should be ‘Setting_A and setting_B, or setting_X and setting_Y, cannot be added…’? (and suggests ‘neither A… nor X…’)
Grammatically or scientifically, how is it OK to use ‘setting_A and setting_B, or setting_X and setting_Y…’ when the meaning is clearly not ‘… or…’ but ‘… and…’?